# Maven Build some modules, liferay:deploy others

Tags: maven, deployment, liferay

I have some modules like:

|-business jar

|-dal jar

|-model jar

|-webApp war

I need to build all jar before liferay:deploy the war. 
I also have a parent pom module that allow to build all modules but it doesn't deploy my war after that.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined all modules as dependencies then maven will take care that the modules build in the proper order.

By default the Liferay deploy goal is not executed. You need execute it or add some configuration to run tit automatically. e.g.

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <pluginType>portlet</pluginType>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>deploy-package</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your parent pom contains all the modules in the

`<modules>
    <module>business-jar</module>
    <module>dal-jar</module>
    <module>model-jar</module>
    <module>portlet</module>
    <module>theme</module>
 </modules>`

and then make sure that your portlet/webapp war does contain

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy-package</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>deploy</goal>
                  </goals>
                </executions>               
            </plugin>
```